# Command line to return to the GUI after Ctrl-Alt-F1?

Tags: linux, xorg, console

I'm unable to return to the GUI with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or any of the 12 function keys). I have some unsaved work and I don't want to lose them. **Are there any other key combinations that will allow me to switch back?**

Here is what I did:

1. I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and it showed a text-based login screen as usual
2. Then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and it showed a screen full of text (I can't remember what they were)
3. Then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and it showed log messages that resembles `/var/log/messages`. Some entries are from `automount`, some from `sendmail`, and none are errors.
4. Pressing any of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> combinations now has no effect. The cap-lock and num-lock LED no longer respond to their corresponding keys. I can use the mouse to highlight the text on the screen, but nothing else.

Any idea what happened?

I can still login to the system via SSH. GUI applications that I was using (e.g. `opera`) are still running and consuming tiny amounts of CPU as usual, as reported by `top`. **Is it possible to switch back to the GUI via the command line?** If possible, I don't want to restart X, because doing so will kill all the GUI applications.

System info:

```
 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.7
 Linux 2.6.18-238.12.1.el5 SMP x86_64
 gnome-desktop: 2.16.0-1.fc6
 xorg-x11-server-Xorg: 1.1.1-48.76.el5_7.5
```

---

Thanks to Shawn I was able to get back using `chvt 9`.

Further experiments shows that if I go to the 8th virtual terminal (either by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> or `chvt 8`), I will not be able to switch to any other terminals using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> keys. Now sure if this is a bug.

Comment: On a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B (what I am using):
After you hit Ctrl+Alt+F1, it brought you to the command line. On mine, you can it Ctrl+Alt+F2 and it will take you to the Pi login.
Just login and after that type startx, then you will be taken back to the desktop :)

Comment: @user114432 In no system I've ever used has `startx` returned to an existing X session. It always starts a new session on a new console (or the same console, depending on the distro). And AFAIK there is no way to translocate a running client from one X session to another.

Comment: "...if I go to the 8th virtual terminal (either by Ctrl-Alt-F8 or chvt 8), I will not be able to switch to any other terminals using Ctrl-Alt-Fx keys."
Not sure why `chvt 8` would do this. But if you keep the Ctrl+Alt keys held down, after you get back into the graphical mode (aka. the GUI / X server), and press another F1-F12 function key, it will not work. You have to first release the Ctrl+Alt keys, and try again, to get out of the graphical mode. I assume this is because the graphical mode doesn't recognise that the keys were pushed down because it wasn't activated at that point in time?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`chvt` allows you to change your virtual terminal.

From `man chvt`:

> The command chvt N makes /dev/ttyN the foreground terminal. (The
>   corresponding screen is created if it did not exist yet. To get rid of
>   unused VTs, use deallocvt(1).) The key combination (Ctrl-)LeftAlt-FN
>   (with N in the range 1-12) usually has a similar effect.

Comment: Could he have used `startx` as well? Just wondering.

Comment: @MaxMackie that should result in an error, since x server is already running.

Comment: You also need to run this as root

Comment: You may not need to run this as root if you use `gdm` where it starts a root-less display session as the user. In that case `tty2` appears to be allocated for the user with `tty7` for the gdm owned login window. If you switch to `tty7` you have to login again and then it will push you back over to `tty2` automatically, or you can simply switch to `tty2` yourself.

Comment: This definitely helped out. I'm not sure why Ctrl+Alt+F7 no longer works to get back to the GUI vt, like it always used to. Thanks for the answer that's helped me sort myself out.

Comment: Same problem as OP in Ubuntu 18.10, `chv 0t` says no such device, `w` shows that my gnome TTY is :0

Answer (score 26):

Use the `w` command to find out which tty your X session uses, so you won't need to guess which <kbd>Fn</kbd> to press.

Comment: Here `w` lists tty1, tty2 and tty3 while X is running on tty12.

Comment: Exellect answer, just wordering. I go to console by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1, see console tty1, unable to go back by the same combo. Use w, see I have 2 sessions tty1 and tty7, and return by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F7. Is It logical? Is It normal?

Comment: what if my TTY is 0? there is no F0 button

Answer (score 23):

You can simply use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to return to your desktop.

Comment: In the TTY, C-A-F# and A-F# are equivalent.

Comment: Yes.  Surprise to me, after 20 years of X being on tty > 6 my current CentOS/KDM install uses tty1

Answer (score 5):

You can use Alt+F6 to return to your desktop in Fedora 26 and possibly other Wayland based Linux flavors.

Comment: FFS, I don't know why this isn't the accepted answer.  The OP gave their freaking OS in the question, and this is by FAR the least faffing about answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Toggle function-keys pressing "F-Lock" (german "F-Umsch")**

Stumpling right into the same problem, I've found the reason for - at least - my problem:
Using a ms natural 4000 keyboard sometimes requires to toggle the Function-keys pressing "F-Lock"-key located next to F12.

(Toggling the Function-Key's might help with that type of keyboard too if you don't get hardcopies etc...)

Comment: This is not the problem of the OP, thanks for the effort, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the English version of what the other answers said:

1. First, log in if it asks you to do so.
2. Then, run the `w` command. It will give you a `tty#` for your desktop GUI.
3. Then, either press `F#` or run `sudo chvt #`, matching the `#` from step 2.
4. If that doesn't work, panic.