# Return to QT5 app after going to other virtual terminal Ctrl-Alt-F1

Tags: opengl

I've got an app made in QT5 running in fullscreen. If I move to a virtual terminal, using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> key combination for example, then there is no way I can find to go back to my QT5 app.

What I am missing? Does the QT5 app executes in other place rather than a virtual terminal?

Answer (score 1):

*Usually* X on Linux is running in **`vt7`**. Occasionally bugs are reported in switching to/from, but not that often, likewise it is configurable.  See for example

- [5.1 Linux essential keyboard shortcuts and sanity commands](http://linux.about.com/od/linux101/l/blnewbie5_1.htm)
- [Command line to return to the GUI after Ctrl-Alt-F1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23363/command-line-to-return-to-the-gui-after-ctrl-alt-f1)
- [Ctrl-Alt-F7 to restore Gui not working Ubuntu 10.10](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1712424)